# Problem with the firefox webdriver for selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run any of the scripts I wrote that use Selenium but I am unable to run any of them them.

Every time I try I get the same:

Error Message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service geckodriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 64
```

This error message appears literally at the beginning, for example, it is enough to write:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

It appears right on the first line of code.

Comment: I solved the issue, I just had to update python and geckodriver to the newest version. I do not know if this actually solved the problem or is it just a coincidence that everything works normally now.